# Typesetting LaTeX in a text cell

Tags: cells, style, text, latex, matex

I recently started trying to use stylesheets and different cell types to organize and explain my logic. Often I try to type equations into my text cells to explain what I'm doing, but this can be rather tedious and the resulting equations are often hard to read (especially when trying to type bra-ket notation), I'm wondering if there's a way to render LaTeX in my text cells?

Comment: You can type a LaTeX string in a `"Text"` cell and then paste it into a new cell and it should format. If that doesn't work you can do this, too: `ImportString["$\log(x)^2$", {"TeX", "Cell"}][[1]] // CellPrint`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The ease (or lack of) of typing math in Mathematica? Or the typesetting quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need [MaTeX package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).
This is the [official website](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX) of MaTeX package.

Comment: this package is immensely helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

In MMA 12.2 this is now possible in text boxes using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + `$`, see the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineTeXInput.html).

Comment: Just curious....Have you tried the MaTeX package? How does MMA's latex environment compare? With MMA 12.2 being relatively new, I'm wondering if you've found it "buggy"?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack I haven't used the new functionality much, but they serve different purposes. MaTeX can be used to generate LaTeX labels to put into graphics, while the new TeX support is for text cells, at least that's what I understand (I'm no expert on either of them)

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked very nicely with a rather monstrous formula written in LaTeX.